# Homestead 2.0 multiple sites, all link to the same url

Tags: laravel, hosts-file

Hee guys, little question: So i have setup the Homestead 2.0 and everything is working fine. I wanted to add another project in the same code directory but link it to another url. So i added it in the sites list but when i visited laravel.app it all works fine, but when I visit larabook.app it shows me the laravel.app page! Both urls are linked to 192.168.10.10 in my /etc/hosts file.

I have tried restarting my mac and restarting the vm but nothing is working :'(

/etc/hosts

```
192.168.10.10 laravel.app
192.168.10.10 larabook.app
```

Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: larabook.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Larabook/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - larabook
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assuming your Homestead.yaml file above

type in:

```
$ vagrant global-status
```

will display something like;

```
id    name      provider   state   directory    
--------------------------------------------    
77c5c30  default   virtualbox running et....
```

type in:

```
$ vagrant provision 77c5c30
```

Of course this assumes you only have 1 VM, if you have others then read the instruction when you run vagrant provision

Comment: This is really working for Homestead 2. I had the same problem and tried to use `homestead` or `default` as Vagrant box name to provision it after adding new sites but the above method is working at the moment like a charm

Comment: Worked using Homestead 2 and Vagrant 1.7 - What is really happening here? would love to know :)

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks a lot. Laravel guide should include this very crucial step. You're a genius to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, and didn't lose the database:

```
$ homestead halt
$ homestead up --provision
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Code/Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel

    - map: ~/Code/Larabook
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Larabook

sites:
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: larabook.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Larabook/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - larabook
```

Note: look at the changes i have made to the folders section.
find out more from https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/configuring-multiple-laravel-homestead-sites-and-databases/#top

```
after run
    $ homestead halt
    $ homestead up --provision
```