# Homestead / Vagrant not provisioning or serving additional sites

Tags: vagrant, homestead, vagrant-provision

I'm attempting to run multiple sites in my Homestead box, `wordpress.dev` and `responsible.dev`. However, upon navigating to `http://responsible.dev` it displays the content from `wordpress.dev`.

I've set up the sites in my `Homestead.yaml` and `hosts` file, and ran various attempts of:

- `vagrant provision`
- `vagrant provision <vm_id>`
- `vagrant reload --provision`
- `vagrant destroy` followed by `vagrant up`
- `vagrant ssh` followed by `serve responsible.dev /home/vagrant/Code/responsible`

but nothing seems to be working.

The output of `vagrant up` / `vagrant provision` shows it creating the `wordpress.dev` site, but not `provision.dev`

[image: vagrant up]

but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong for it to be skipping over.

My `Homestead.yaml` file:

```html
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: wordpress.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/wordpress
    - map: responsible.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/responsible

databases:
    - homestead
```

and `hosts` file:

```html
192.168.10.10   wordpress.dev
192.168.10.10   responsible.dev
```

I assume it is something basic and obvious that I am over-looking, but I can't for the life of me see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homestead 2.0 multiple sites, all link to the same url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207150/homestead-2-0-multiple-sites-all-link-to-the-same-url)

Comment: I don't believe it is; visited that thread whilst trying to find solutions and have tried the steps outlined in there to no avail!